# Чтение из MySQL в php-скрипт

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, php8

При попытке вывести данные из таблицы mysql в скрипт php выдает ошибку:
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect()

Код скрипта:

```
<head></head>
<body><div id="rez"><?php
phpinfo();
$host = 'localhost';  
  $user = 'root';
  $pass = 'passwd';
  $db_name = 'DB_NAME';   // 
  $link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db_name);

  // Если ошибка
  if (!$link) {
    echo 'Ошибка коннекта номер: ' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ', ошибка: ' . mysqli_connect_error();
    exit;
  }
  
  $sql = mysql_query($link, 'SELECT `id`, `Stable`, `Points` FROM `results`');
  while ($result = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
    echo "{$result['Stable']}: {$result['Points']} <br>";
  }

?></div>
    </body>
```

В файле php.ini строки раскомментированы:

```
extension=bz2
extension=curl
extension=ffi
extension=ftp
extension=fileinfo
extension=gd
extension=gettext
extension=gmp
extension=intl
extension=imap
extension=ldap
extension=mbstring
extension=exif      
extension=mysqli
extension=oci8_12c  
extension=oci8_19  
extension=odbc
extension=openssl
extension=pdo_firebird
extension=pdo_mysql
extension=pdo_oci
extension=pdo_odbc
extension=pdo_pgsql
extension=pdo_sqlite
extension=pgsql
extension=shmop

extension=soap
extension=sockets
extension=sodium
extension=sqlite3
extension=tidy
extension=xsl
```

Что Еще нужно сделать, чтобы код начал работать и считывать строку из базы данных?

Comment: mysql установить надо, а так-то лучше pdo используйте

Comment: @InDevX mysql установлен

Comment: Если Вы уверены что установлено, значит не видит расширения. Добавьте extension_dir

Comment: @InDevX в php.ini строчка extension_dir = "C:\Server\bin\PHP\ext\" Там же по идее и хранятся расширения?

Comment: Не знаю папки, давно не пользовался окнами. Смотрите есть ли там php_mysqli.dll

Comment: @InDevX Есть такой файл

Comment: Странно.. Не знаю что сказать.. Самое время на [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/pdo.construct.php) переходить

Comment: @InDevX Можете подсказать насчет этого подробнее?

Answer (score 0):

В терминале выполнить

```
sudo apt install php-mysqli
```

Comment: Все стоит на windows 10